# If I don't travel on a UK visit visa and it expires, will it hurt my chances of getting a visa in the future?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I'm from Pakistan and I applied for a UK visitor visa for a company trip that got cancelled. However, my visa application was successful and I now have a valid 6-month visit visa to the United Kingdom. Now I hear from a bunch of people that if you don't travel on a visitor visa to the UK and it expires, your chances of ever getting a visa to the UK again are almost nonexistent. I obviously cannot find any such thing on any official source. Can anybody here share what they know on whether that's actually the case or not?

Thanks!

Comment: Given the biggest worry they have when approving your visa is that you'll come and never leave, it would seem an odd result - if anything, not travelling suggests that you *really* aren't interested in illegally moving there.

Comment: Whoever told you that is talking nonsense: A VISA gives you permission to travel to the UK, not an obligation to do so. It's understood that plans sometimes change, particularly for business travel.

Comment: It's an old tale I also heard several times back in the day in my country. It probably got legs because a few people who obtained visas and never traveled were subsequently denied visas when they reapplied. People thought being issued a visa once automatically meant an approval for subsequent application and hence when those people were refused, the default explanation was **aha, they issued you a visa and you did not use it, they are upset at you and now you're finished**

Comment: Thanks to everyone who responded, this was very helpful! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the list of things **you cannot do** for this type of visa

- not comming to the UK at all

is not listed.
(it is also not listed as something you can do)

https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa

---

If you want to play it save, ask your company to write a short letter confirming that they cancelled the intended trip.

This could then be shown/submitted during the next visa application.